# npm installation error in ubuntu14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, react-native, titanium-alloy, titanium-android, npm-install

I am trying to configure Titanium Appcelerator studio in Ubuntu 14.04.
I have almost configured everything but not able to install Appcelerator CLI. 
Whenever i try to setup i am getting below error:

```
Finding latest version ...5.1.0 ✓
Validating security checksum ✓
Installing ... ✓
Compiling platform native modules ...
└ extract-opts/typechecker ... ✓
└ bunyan/dtrace-provider ...  ✓
└ extract-opts/typechecker ...  ✓
└ socket.io-client/ws ...  ✓
└ appc-ldapjs/dtrace-provider ...  ✓
└ bunyan/dtrace-provider ...  ✓
└ appc-ldapjs/dtrace-provider ...  ✓
└ ws/bufferutil ...  ✓
└ ws/utf-8-validate ...  ✓
└ chokidar/fsevents ... npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-73-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/home/user/.linuxbrew/bin/npm" "install" "fsevents@1.0.5" "--production"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.5
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/arrow/node_modules/babel/node_modules/chokidar/npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone have any solution? 
Please help me i am trying it out hard but not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the following issue:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-489

Please watch it and add your information. I'll ask to for it to be reopened.

Comment: I have already applied this solution. Its doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK. The ticket has been reopened for triage soon.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still occurs, but i added another comment to the ticket on jira.
The fix proposed over there by @Far does work on (X)Ubuntu 14.04, at least for me.

Of course the prerequisites, like node etc. have to be installed, but then it should be working.
The actual link for this ticket is now:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/CLI-916

---

I did install the cli first, as the login/setup procedure is better IMHO:

```
sudo npm install -g appcelerator
```

Add the fix from the ticket (for me it was line **159** in ***/usr/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/lib/install.js***)

Then:

```
appc setup
```

If the Fix is working, you should be greeted with the prompt for username(email) and password, followed by the 4 digit device activation code, sent to your email address (after seeing all the fancy cli download stuff).

The authorization will be saved in your home directory, so now you can download the studio zip from their page, unpack it and just run it. Login should allready be active.

Happy devtime :)